# Rmarkdown, plot title font as latin modern

Tags: plot, knitr, latin-modern, rmarkdown

I have an `knitr` document with single plot. I want to use the original fonts of `R` in the plot except the axis labels which should come from latin modern. I can use latin modern for all the fonts in the plot by `tikzDevice` package of `R`. But compiling this takes too much time when the data set used for plotting is very big.

OR, Can I use `tikzDevice` only for labels and title of the plot?

A summary code is below:

```
<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(tikzDevice)
#opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz') # I don't want to use tikzDevice.
opts_chunk$set(dev.args=list(pointsize=12)) 
@

<<tikzfigure, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4, fig.align = 'center', fig.pos = 'ht', tidy = TRUE>>=

plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=paste0("$\\sum \\beta_i$"))
@
```

The output:

[image]

The plot should stay as the same except the `x label` should be

[image]

(latin modern font.)

How can I achieve this?

(Note: I asked the question stackoverflow as well, but I think this is the correct place for it. I don't know if this is a problem...)

Comment: The solution to have tolerable compilation times is not avoid `tikz ` but avoid  `cache=FALSE`.

Comment: For the record, it was cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62490683/559676.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `latex2exp` library to parse the `LaTeX` code in your label. Make sure you have a font that contains the italic beta. I used I used CM-Unicode. You can access the glyph using the unicode representation `\u03B2` or as the character `β`.

Here is a complete MWE in `knitr` (`.Rnw` file):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
rm(list = ls())
library(knitr)
library(latex2exp)
library(showtext)
font_add("CMUSerif-RomanSlanted",regular="c:/windows/fonts/cmunsl_0.ttf")
#library(tikzDevice)
#opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz') # I don't want to use tikzDevice.
opts_chunk$set(dev.args=list(pointsize=12))
@

\begin{document}
<<chunk1, echo = FALSE, fig.width = 4, fig.height = 4>>=
plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=TeX("$\\sum \\textit{\u03B2_i}$"))
plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=TeX("$\\sum \\textit{\u03B2_i}$",list(family="CMUSerif-RomanSlanted")))
plot(1:5,1:5,xlab=TeX("$\\sum \\textit{β_i}$",list(family="CMUSerif-RomanSlanted")))
@
\end{document}
```

Giving this:

[image]

Comment: Ross (+1) Thanks for the response. Actually I know this approach but I would like to get latin modern math fonts (upright digits, italic letters etc.) on the labels.

Comment: @mert. I updated with the italic beta.